# Update paypal billing amount

Tags: php, paypal, billing

I'm trying to create an app that allows people to have subscription for when they would add something new that requires monthly billing, rather then creating a whole new billing plan for each item it would be handy to just update the billing plan so it will take out the new amount with the next due transaction.

but the problem i'm encountering is the following every time i execute the function

> "issue":"Invalid Path provided."

I've tried variations of the path and it's required input:

php variations:

```
->setPath('/payment-definitions/amount')

->setPath('/payment_definitions/amount')

->setPath('/payment-definitions')

->setPath('/payment_definitions')
```

json input variations:

```
{"value":"$amount"}

{"amount":{"value":"$amount"}}
```

what I've read from [the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans#plan_update) page at least one of them should be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my answer after digging though the git.
 [Here it is](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/billing/UpdatePlanPaymentDefinitions.php)

However **you can only update it when it's in the state "created"**